# git update remote server after repo rollback

Tags: git

was working on master when should have been on a branch, so I made a branch & then rolled back to the last good commit with:

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

I then pushed master with:

```
git push origin master -f
```

This leaves my repo in correct condition - I can see it is all correct on my gitlab page & when I pull locally it is correctly up-to-date

I have a development server that is currently on branch "master" & I am now trying to "pull the reset" for lack of the correct expression - set it back to where my local machine is. However, any fetches or pulls all result in it telling me that I'm already up-to-date

From dev server git branch -a

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

What is the correct procedure here?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to complete delete your master branch on development server and than clean checkout:

```
# Make master backup    
git checkout master && git checkout -b old-master

# Delete your local master
git branch -D master

# Checkout master from origin
git checkout master

# In case something is wrong - restore backup
git branch -D master && git branch -m old-master master

# If all is ok delete backup
git branch -D old-master
```

Comment: ah...I think there must be a more direct way? Instead of that, I guess I would just rollback on development as well

Comment: In my solution you'll get same history on development server. In case of local rollback i'm not sure.

Comment: I'll keep it as an option, but see what other ideas come up. Has a bit of a "reboot your machine" feel to it :-)

Comment: I guess in the end that was the easiest way to go. Thanks for your help, including great "what to do if" code to restore